# ASP .NET Core MVC Enity Framework - get access to rows from many-to-many relationship table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my SQL Server in Visual Studio I have TripApplicationUser table which is a result of many-to-many relationship between ApplicationUser and Trip. This table consists of TripId and ApplicationUserId. I store there that a specific user has enrolled for a specific trip. I would like to check if user has enrolled for a given trip.

```
var currentTrip = await _context.Trip.FindAsync(id);
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var isAlreadyEnrolled = _context.TripApplicationUsers.Where(tu => tu.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id && tu.TripId == id);
List<TripApplicationUser> UserTrips = await isAlreadyEnrolled.ToListAsync();
```

I get error in the 4th line:

> InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to
> evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception
> for more information. To show additional information call
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TripApplicationUser> TripApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }

public class Trip
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public string TripDate { get; set; }
        public int TripDuration { get; set; }
        public int TripLength { get; set; }
        public int TripSeats { get; set; }

        public int TrailId { get; set; }
        public Trail Trail { get; set; }


        public ICollection<TripApplicationUser> TripApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }

public class TripApplicationUser
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: need more info on the inner exception - do as the message says = `DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'

Comment: @Jazb https://pastebin.pl/view/be64ef51

Comment: @Jazb I have enabled sensitive data logging and now I get diffrent error: https://pastebin.com/7yQGqdBG

Comment: currentUser is null when trying to use it for the Id property

Comment: improve your code by checking for nulls - don't assume anything